# why my bill in aws ec2 is so high?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an application which is streaming some audio from amazon s3.and also using some php code hosted in ec2.i have using a community ami to launch an instance its of type m1 small.but in my usage report aws compute cloud costs 61$ for a month.also i am using 1 elastic IP.there is 0$ for s3 usage in that report,the bills are seems to be really huge.it is seems to be quite unnatural.can anybody help me to sort out this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which os are you using? if it's linux, $61 is pretty much what I calculated since you're running a small instance (Linux/Small/24h per day). I'm not sure you actually need a **small** one - please consider using the **micro** one to be eligible of the free tier usage.

However, I hope the calculator helps you: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Regards,
Piotr

Comment: ya its a linux instance community ami image based instance

Comment: That would be it. Check out the micro instances (I've been using a micro windows one for quite a while now), to reduce your bills.

Comment: so u think that its a normal bill?i was using only one sqlite db.

Comment: Well, if the machine was up all the time, I would expect so. If I were you I would check when it was actually booted and how long did it run for last month.

Comment: can u pls tell me how it would be done?

Comment: Go to your management console -> ec2 -> instances -> select your instance -> in the properties you should see the launch time. In my case it is: Launch Time: 2012-05-28 13:45 GMT (866 hours)

Comment: it is 2012-06-05 12:58 GMT+0530 (679 hours)

Comment: there is only one solution changing its type to micro exists.is it?

Comment: Well, that's it then. It's a normal bill I'm afraid. Micro instance would give you 750 hours of free computing per month - reducing small to micro would be my advice.

Comment: is there any other way to solve the issue

Comment: Can u give me one advice,if i changed it to micro ,then i need to take the back up of the sqlite db in side that instance everyday.how can i do that.i was really looking forward to cooperate with u ,can u add me in gtalk,or something like that

Comment: I haven't moved any instance myself, but this seems to be a good tutorial: http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-change-type

Comment: i know that,i really want to know how to back up my ec2 instance/

Comment: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateImage.html

Comment: You should start a bounty on this question

Comment: Alternatively you can simply create an image straight from your management console (instance actions).

Comment: but it is not good to create it everyday i think?

Comment: Why would you want to create a backup of your machine everyday? Don't you mean a backup of the db only? I think you should formulate what you want to achieve and start a new question.

Comment: A good way (no, THE way) to bring the price of always-up (or mostly up) EC2 instances down is through reserved instances http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/, especially if you're happy with a 3-year commit.

Answer (score 3):

A small instance costs $0.08 an hour.  There are approximately 750 hours in a month that is $60 total per month.  They probably have taxes too.  Now, I know you said it is being launched by a community AMI, but I think if your instance is not booted you have to pay for your elastic IP each hour $0.01 which  isn't too much, but can be minimized if you use the Amazon Route53 DNS for it.

My thoughts:

- Maybe your EC2 instance is staying on longer than you expected

If you are still concerned.  I would talk to Amazon's support.

Answer (score 1):

Try [spot instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/).  The ec2 spot instance price is .007 per hour.  You should be able to significantly reduce the $61/mo charge.  When requesting a spot instance, you can use the on-demand price of .08 per hour and you'll pay the lowest rate up to .08 per hour, after which your instance will be terminated.  I run spot instances and bid to on-demand prices and have yet to have one terminated.  You can also buy a [reserved instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/) to obtain a cheaper hourly rate.